# bootstrap scrollspy skipping first element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I am working with Bootstrap `scrollspy.js v3.3.5` and I have a little problem.

I have a fixed header on my page that takes 100px on top and it is over the first element of my element list. This is ok.

So, I put scrollspy to work.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav">

    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#nav' });

    <div id="nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs list-group" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#index-mod-1"><span>1</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#index-mod-2"><span>2</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#index-mod-3"><span>3</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#index-mod-4"><span>4</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#index-mod-5"><span>5</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#index-mod-6"><span>6</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Body with relative position. #nav floating fixed on screen's right. All the elements watched in page with `display:table, width:100%, position:relative`.

But, when I load the page, scrollspy removes the active class from first #nav's li and puts it on the second.

I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the first element has an height minor than the viewport height, so the scrollspy call for the second element.